# Modify Maven's classpath

Tags: maven, maven-2, classpath, maven-plugin

I'm looking for a way to modify the class path in maven. Why?

I want to instrument maven artifacts without corrupting the local repository such that when surefire-tests run it will see the instrumented classpath, not the original class path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general maven manages the classpath by itself.
Having said that,  there are a couple of options you can try here:

- You can use 'additionalClassPath' parameter in surefire plugin. You can read about it[here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/configuring-classpath.html):
- You can generate your instrumented jars and use them in scope test, don't use un-instrumented jars in the tests at all

Hope this helps